# Grant read access to S3 bucket owner for native backup across AWS accounts

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

In AWS, I create a SQL Server native backup to an S3 bucket owned by a secondary AWS account.

How can I automatically give a secondary account role(s)/users read access to a backup file/object?

During ordinary file-copy to a secondary S3 account, I can use (PowerShell)

```
Set-S3ACL ... -CannedACLName "bucket-owner-full-control"
```

or

```
Write-S3Object ... -CannedACLName "bucket-owner-full-control"
```

However, I cannot find such an option when calling (Sql Server Agent)

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database
```

and I cannot execute PowerShell calls from an AWS hosted SQL Server instance.

My workaround is to log in to the primary AWS account and execute Set-S3ACL manually.

Database Server Instance Snapshots are not an option.

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Agent.html